# Contenteditable and Block-selected Backspace Performance Issue

Tags: angular, performance, contenteditable

I'm using Angular 9.1.7 and a contenteditable div to create a basic text editing capability in my application. I've bound a number of event handlers to this div, but the thing I've stumbled upon that is puzzling me is what happens when I select a paragraph of text in the div and type the backspace key.

TL;DR **UPDATE**
I've created a minimal reproducible example [here on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rpjvmh?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Just try and delete one of the paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum text to see what I mean.

The whole browser process seems to hang for a little while (> 10 seconds). I can't click on anything else, scroll, etc. The UI is completely out of my control, until suddenly it's not and the effect of the backspace is rendered (the block of text I had selected is deleted). I put in a bunch of console logs in some event handlers and came out with this sequence of events:

```
keydown
keydown
beforeinput start
beforeinput end
input start
input end
// ... out to lunch for a few seconds ...
keyup start
keyup end
```

... I also timed the start -> end of all those events and the duration of their execution is negligible. So I can't find anywhere in my code that is hogging the processor and jamming up the browser UI. I ran the Chrome Dev Tools profiler and see things like this:

[image]

... and if I scroll into where the beginning of where purple stuff starts happening I see this:
[image]

As far as how Angular is engaged with the contenteditable div, it's a ViewChild of my component that looks like this in the markup:

```html
      <div #editableText contenteditable="true"
        (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)"
        (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"
        (keypress)="onKeyPress($event)"
        (input)="onInput($event)"
        (beforeinput)="onBeforeInput($event)"><br></div>
```

... and I intercept the keying events to determine and structure the innerHTML of the element to suit my needs. This manifests in the component as:

```js
@ViewChild('editableText', { static: false }) editableElem: ElementRef;
...
updateEditableText(html) {
  this.editableElem.nativeElement.innerHTML = html;
}
```

I've checked and the updateEditableText function is not being called repeatedly or implicated in the performance issue in any way as far as I can tell.

I'm not sure how to get any more insight than that into what's going on here, and I'm not sure if this is something to do with Angular change detection or something more directly attributable to contenteditable. The markup, within the contenteditibale, underlying my selection to be deleted amounts to several `span` elements with data attributes associated with them, but I can't understand why the complexity of the contenteditable markup should matter to me simply selecting a block of content and hitting backspace.

I'm seeking for advice on how to get to the bottom of what is going on here (e.g. different use of the Chrome dev tools profiler, Angular diagnostic techniques, etc.) and to pinpoint the source of this performance bottleneck so that I can either fix it or work around the problem.

Comment: I see someone has voted to close, I'm not asking multiple questions, just providing ample detail and background. The question I am asking is, how best can I determine what the browser is doing when the UI becomes temporarily unresponsive.

Comment: So what calls updateEditableText? This sounds like some kind of recursive thing happening maybe..? If you can recreate your issue in a simple stackblitz it would probably be easier to determine what might be happening..

Comment: That's a fair point @MikeOne but I use moment to timetamp the entry to that function and moment to calculate the execution time of that function prior to exit and it takes < 100ms to execute. I will try to make a stackblitz though and post back here if I can.

Comment: @MikeOne I've added a stackblitz to the post

Comment: Okay, I can see the delay - and this makes sense.. You're creating 15,000 dom elements there... Why the wrap in <spans>?

Comment: @MikeOne Basically for ease of addressing individual characters quickly. You'll notice that typing and into the contenteditable and deleting individual characters is not slow... just deleting a larger block of text. Maybe I should just try and detect that specific event and wholesale replace the innerHTML based on a calculated result in that case.